# Comparing index positions of sublists in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm trying to understand what I'm missing in these two different methods.  In the code below, I'm defining a list of lists, and calling it two ways.  The first way is to call it in a print statement as one line, separating the index positions of the lists with commas, the second is to print them all separately.

```py
list_of_lists = [[2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
print(list_of_lists[0][0],[1][0],[2][0])
print('\n')
```

The output of this code is `2,1,2`

```py
print(winner_is_2[0][0])
print(winner_is_2[1][0])
print(winner_is_2[2][0])
```

The output of this code is `2,2,2`

Why, in the first case, does the call output the wrong value for the second set of index positions?

The use case here is trying to check if a set of index positions in a list of lists is all equal to the same value (like you'd see in tic-tac-toe where you'd check if all the values in row x or column y are the same)

**NOTE:**  I know I can use list extraction to get all the values at X position in these sublists, but I'd rather not use that method if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet here:

```py
list_of_lists = [[2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
print(list_of_lists[0][0],[1][0],[2][0])
print('\n')
```

This is actually equivalent to:

```py
list_of_lists = [[2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
print(list_of_lists[0][0])
print([1][0])
print([2][0])
```

Python is interpreting the comma separated inputs as separate arrays `[1]` and `[2]` indexed by their first value `[1][0]` and `[2][0]` which leads to them being printed as `1,2`

To see further evidence of this, try changing the values of 1 and 2 and seeing what you get by doing:

```py
list_of_lists = [[2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
print(list_of_lists[0][0],[5555][0],[262626][0])
print('\n')
```

Here you should get `(2, 5555, 262626)`

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_lists = [[2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
    print(list_of_lists[0][0], list_of_lists[1][0], list_of_lists[2][0])
    print('\n')
```

Whats wrong with this?
What you trying is equivalent to:

```
print(list_of_lists[0][0], 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a little more digging, thanks to [Spencer Bard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5001090/spencer-bard) for explaining the syntax mistake, I was able to come up with code that works for precisely what I was trying to do.  As I'm attempting to test a marker against each item at specific index positions within a list, the code that worked for me was as follows.

```
    def win_check(marker_list,mark):
        if (marker_list[0][0] == mark and marker_list[1][0] == mark and marker_list[2][0] == mark):
            print(f'Winner is player {mark}!')
```

There are a lot more elif statements underneath that to account for the rest of the possibilities, but this is the general format.